Trying sort the table: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'textContent')
I trying to sort the balances in the table. But there was a problem. I was try to sort with code:
function sortTableByBalance() {
    const table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    const arr = Array.from(table.rows, row => [row, +row.cells[2].textContent]).slice(1);
    arr.sort(([,a], [,b]) => a - b);
    for (const [elem] of arr) {
        table.appendChild(elem);
    }
}

that was suggested to me in another question. But javascript console in browser showed me the error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'textContent')

The stage at which this error shows me:
const sortBtnBalance = document.querySelector(".sort-balance-btn");
sortBtnBalance.addEventListener("click", sortTableByBalance);
function sortTableByBalance() {
  const table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  const tableRows = table.rows;
  const arrs = Array.from(tableRows, (row) => [
    row,
    +row.cells[3].textContent,
  ]).slice(1, -1);
}

I assume that js complains about an empty cell in a column, because I remove all unnecessary lines using slice after I display the textContent of the cells of these same lines. But I still don’t understand how to fix this.
My tableRender with javascript:
// дать нам новый массив объектов
const usrs = getUsers();

// основной контейнер для таблицы
const usersContainer = document.querySelector(
  ".users-list-section .users-group"
);

// статическая thead таблицы
function theadTemplate() {
  // создать элемент thead
  const thead = document.createElement("thead");
  // создать элемент tr
  const tr = document.createElement("tr");
  // создать элемент th1 и дать ему атрибуты
  const th1 = document.createElement("th");
  th1.setAttribute("scope", "col");
  th1.textContent = "#";

  /* reset sort btn */
  const resetSortBtn = document.createElement("button");
  resetSortBtn.setAttribute("type", "button");
  resetSortBtn.addEventListener("click", renderUsers);
  resetSortBtn.classList.add("btn", "btn-dark", "reset-sort-btn");

  const i0 = document.createElement("i");
  i0.classList.add("bi", "bi-arrow-clockwise", "reset-clockwise");

  resetSortBtn.appendChild(i0);
  th1.appendChild(resetSortBtn);

  // создать элемент th2 и дать ему атрибуты
  const th2 = document.createElement("th");
  th2.setAttribute("scope", "col");
  th2.textContent = "Name";
  // sort btn для сортировки юзеров по именам
  const sortBtnNames = document.createElement("button");
  sortBtnNames.setAttribute("type", "button");
  sortBtnNames.setAttribute("onclick", "namesSortHandler(1)");
  sortBtnNames.classList.add("btn", "btn-dark", "sort-names-btn");
  // иконка стрелка
  const i1 = document.createElement("i");
  i1.classList.add("bi", "bi-arrow-up", "sort-names-arrow");

  // добавить стрелку в кнопку и кнопку в th
  sortBtnNames.appendChild(i1);
  th2.appendChild(sortBtnNames);
  // создать элемент th3 и дать ему атрибуты
  const th3 = document.createElement("th");
  th3.setAttribute("scope", "col");
  th3.textContent = "Email";
  // создать элемент th4 и дать ему атрибуты
  const th4 = document.createElement("th");
  th4.setAttribute("scope", "col");
  th4.textContent = "Balance";

  // sort btn для сортировки юзеров по балансу
  const sortBtnBalance = document.createElement("button");
  sortBtnBalance.setAttribute("type", "button");
  sortBtnBalance.classList.add("btn", "btn-dark", "sort-balance-btn");
  // иконка стрелка
  const i2 = document.createElement("i");
  i2.classList.add("bi", "bi-arrow-up", "sort-balance-arrow");

  // добавить стрелку в кнопку и кнопку в th
  sortBtnBalance.appendChild(i2);
  th4.appendChild(sortBtnBalance);

  // добавить детей в родителей
  tr.appendChild(th1);
  tr.appendChild(th2);
  tr.appendChild(th3);
  tr.appendChild(th4);
  thead.appendChild(tr);

  // вернуть полноценно собранный thead
  return thead;
}
// полноценно собранный thead из функции записать в переменную.
const thead = theadTemplate();

// tbody таблицы (основное тело, куда будут писаться пользователи.)
function tbodyTemplate({
  _id,
  name,
  email,
  isActive,
  balance,
  number,
  wiki,
} = {}) {
  // создать элемент tbody
  const tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  // создать элемент tr
  const tr = document.createElement("tr");
  // создать элемент th и дать ему классы и стили
  const th = document.createElement("th");
  th.classList.add("table-secondary");

  th.style.color = "black";
  th.style.fontWeight = "bold";
  th.setAttribute("scope", "row");
  th.textContent = number;

  // создать элемент tdName и дать ему классы и стили
  const tdName = document.createElement("td");
  tdName.classList.add("table-secondary");
  // nameLink имя с ссылкой на статью в wiki каждого юзера
  const nameLink = document.createElement("a");
  nameLink.setAttribute("href", wiki);
  nameLink.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
  nameLink.style.color = "black";
  nameLink.style.fontWeight = "bold";
  nameLink.textContent = name;

  // создать элемент tdEmail и дать ему классы и стили
  const tdEmail = document.createElement("td");
  tdEmail.classList.add("table-secondary");
  tdEmail.style.color = "black";
  tdEmail.style.fontWeight = "bold";
  tdEmail.textContent = email;

  // создать элемент tdBalance и дать ему классы и стили
  const tdBalance = document.createElement("td");
  tdBalance.classList.add("table-secondary", "tdbalance");
  tdBalance.style.color = "black";
  tdBalance.style.fontWeight = "bold";
  tdBalance.textContent = Number(balance);

  // Добавляем детей в родителей, собираем конструкцию
  tr.appendChild(th);
  tdName.appendChild(nameLink);
  tr.appendChild(tdName);
  tr.appendChild(tdEmail);
  tr.appendChild(tdBalance);
  tbody.appendChild(tr);

  // вернуть собранный tbody
  return tbody;
}

// Каркас итогового общего баланса юзеров
function totalBalanceTemplate(balance) {
  // В balance мы передаём массив балансов всех юзеров из функции renderUsers
  // Просуммировать балансы всех юзеров
  const result = balance.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    let result;
    acc = acc + curr;
    result = acc;
    return result;
  }, 0);

  // элемент футера для таблицы
  const tfoot = document.createElement("tfoot");

  // контейнер для строки таблицы
  const tr = document.createElement("tr");

  // сама строка таблицы, здесь примечателен аттрибут colspan
  // в текст контент записываем результат суммирования балансов юзеров с двумя знаками после запятой
  const td = document.createElement("td");
  td.setAttribute("colspan", "4");
  td.style.textAlign = "end";
  td.style.fontWeight = "bold";
  td.textContent = `Total balance: ${result.toFixed(2)}`;

  tr.appendChild(td);
  tfoot.appendChild(tr);

  // вернуть собранный tfoot
  return tfoot;
}

// table таблица и render users отображение в ней пользователей
function renderUsers(usersList) {
  // создать фрагмент
  const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  // создать элемент таблицы и дать ей классы bootstrap
  const table = document.createElement("table", "users-table");
  table.setAttribute("id", "myTable");
  table.classList.add("table-dark", "table", "table-hover", "col");

  // важно создать тотал баланс именно вне foreach и записать его в таблицу так же вне
  // иначе тотал баланс у нас будет висеть после каждого пользователя
  let totalBalance;

  Object.values(usersList).forEach((user) => {
    // создать массив из балансов всех юзеров, записать в result
    let result = usersList.map((user) => Number(user.balance));
    // записать в переменную totalBalance функцию возвращающую каркас(template)
    // передать массив балансов в функцию totalBalanceTemplate
    totalBalance = totalBalanceTemplate(result);
    // здесь записываем тело таблицы в переменную, она возвращает каркас(template)
    // сюда уже передаём просто юзеров
    const tbody = tbodyTemplate(user);
    // добавляем элементы в таблицу
    table.appendChild(thead);
    table.appendChild(tbody);

    fragment.appendChild(table);
  });
  // последний элемент в таблицу, totalBalance
  table.appendChild(totalBalance);
  usersContainer.appendChild(fragment);

  return table;
}
renderUsers(usrs);


My html:
<div class="users-wrapper active">
  <div class="users-list-section mt-5">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="users-group">
        <table
          is="users-table"
          id="myTable"
          class="table-dark table table-hover col"
        >
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th
                class="table-secondary"
                scope="row"
                style="color: black; font-weight: bold;"
              >
                1
              </th>
              <td class="table-secondary">
                <a
                  href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H._P._Lovecraft"
                  target="_blank"
                  style="color: black; font-weight: bold;"
                >
                  Govard Lovecraft
                </a>
              </td>
              <td
                class="table-secondary"
                style="color: black; font-weight: bold;"
              >
                ktulhu@gmail.com
              </td>
              <td
                class="table-secondary tdbalance"
                style="color: black; font-weight: bold;"
              >
                2853.33
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th
                class="table-secondary"
                scope="row"
                style="color: black; font-weight: bold;"
              >
                2
              </th>
              <td class="table-secondary">
                <a
                  href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukio_Mishima"
                  target="_blank"
                  style="color: black; font-weight: bold;"
                >
                  Yukio Mishima
                </a>
              </td>
              <td
                class="table-secondary"
                style="color: black; font-weight: bold;"
              >
                goldenTemple@gmail.com
              </td>
              <td
                class="table-secondary tdbalance"
                style="color: black; font-weight: bold;"
              >
                1464.63
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th
                class="table-secondary"
                scope="row"
                style="color: black; font-weight: bold;"
              >
                3
              </th>
              <td class="table-secondary">
                <a
                  href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taras_Shevchenko"
                  target="_blank"
                  style="color: black; font-weight: bold;"
                >
                  Taras Shevchenko
                </a>
              </td>
              <td
                class="table-secondary"
                style="color: black; font-weight: bold;"
              >
                kobzar@gmail.com
              </td>
              <td
                class="table-secondary tdbalance"
                style="color: black; font-weight: bold;"
              >
                3723.39
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">
                #
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark reset-sort-btn">
                  <i class="bi bi-arrow-clockwise reset-clockwise"></i>
                </button>
              </th>
              <th scope="col">
                Name
                <button
                  type="button"
                  onclick="namesSortHandler(1)"
                  class="btn btn-dark sort-names-btn"
                >
                  <i class="bi bi-arrow-up sort-names-arrow"></i>
                </button>
              </th>
              <th scope="col">Email</th>
              <th scope="col">
                Balance
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark sort-balance-btn">
                  <i class="bi bi-arrow-up sort-balance-arrow"></i>
                </button>
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th
                class="table-secondary"
                scope="row"
                style="color: black; font-weight: bold;"
              >
                4
              </th>
              <td class="table-secondary">
                <a
                  href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dante_Alighieri"
                  target="_blank"
                  style="color: black; font-weight: bold;"
                >
                  Dante Alighieri
                </a>
              </td>
              <td
                class="table-secondary"
                style="color: black; font-weight: bold;"
              >
                laDivinaCommedia@gmail.com
              </td>
              <td
                class="table-secondary tdbalance"
                style="color: black; font-weight: bold;"
              >
                5000.21
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="4" style="text-align: end; font-weight: bold;">
                Total balance: 13041.56
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
        </table>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>;


The problem occurs because the footer row has no third cell in its row. It has a merged cell spanning the whole row. And so the code that accesses cell[2].textContent raises an error because undefined has no textContent property. The slice call looks like an attempt to avoid this, but it comes to late: the error occurs before that slice executes.
One way to resolve this is to only select the tr rows that are child of tbody. Then you shouldn't slice. Add the sorting and it will work:
function sortTableByBalance() {
  const table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  // Only select rows that are not in THEAD or TFOOT:
  const tableRows = table.querySelectorAll("tr:not(thead>tr,tfoot>tr)");
  const arr = Array.from(tableRows, (row) => [row, +row.cells[3].textContent]);
  // No slice... but sort:
  arr.sort(([,a], [,b]) => a - b);
  for (const [elem] of arr) {
    table.appendChild(elem);
  }
}

Other Remarks
With the above change it should work. But there are a few things that could be improved:

Your table creating function creates one tbody per row. Although this is allowed in HTML, this does not have any use in your case, and once you sort, all data rows will be moved out of their parent tbody anyhow. I would suggest adjusting your function, and just remove the tbody wrapping from your code and return the tr instead and append that directly to your table. Alternatively, you could work with exactly one tbody element. If you want the sorted rows to appear in that single tbody element, then make sure to update the above code in that final loop, so that it performs appendChild to that tbody element, not the table.

The code adds the thead in every iteration of the loop. Only the first time it would have a detectable effect. It would make more sense to place this before the loop, so it is only executed once, and also if the table happens to be empty.

Similarly, the addition to the table to the fragment should not be in the loop.

Instead of applying styles directly on your td elements, consider applying CSS classes. This is the better practice.

As you have quite some code repetition to create an element and then set its HTML attributes and text content, it would make sense to make a function for performing these actions on one given element: parameters would be that element, the attribute list and the text content. You could even have an optional argument for child element(s), so that you can create a whole hierarchy of elements in one expression. Or use a library like jQuery, that provides these features.



I'm really very very grateful to you. Thank you. You made me look at my code and the way I write it from a different angle.
